# Tensorflow no module named official

Tags: python, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

Hola buenas estoy intentndo crear un model de Image clasification utilizando el TFlite, el codigo me funcionaba noramalmente hace unos dias y sin ningun problema.
Pero Ahora me sale es no module named official, cuando intento hacer por ejemplo:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.data_util.image_dataloader import ImageClassifierDataLoader
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task import image_classifier
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.model_spec import efficientnet_b0_spec
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.model_spec import ImageModelSpec

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Incluso en el Google Colab del tutorial salta el mismo error pero estube buscando y se soluciona utilizando:

```
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ":/content/models"

import sys
sys.path.append("/content/models")
```

Pero intente hacer lo mimso en mi jupyter notebook utilizando el conda, pero me salio un error, tengo por entendido que el error se soliciona actualizando el PYTHON PATH, la cosa es que intente hacer el codigo para actualizar el

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/models
```

pero me salta un error en syntax, y he intentdo manualmente ver si esta en mis enviroment variables el PyhthonPath pero no esta.
Alguna solucion?

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion, el problema era que no tenia el PYTHONPATH definido y no se define por default, descarge los models en un zip y deje que el PYTHONPATH señalara a el folder y despues de eso actualize los sys variables en el el Jupyter Notebook y me funciono el Official, Espero que os ayude :)